# Bootstrap Responsive turn list into a mobile menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to be able to turn a simple unordered list into a nice menu when on mobile:

```
       <ul class="jumpToList list-inline">
            <li><a href="#buttons">Buttons</a></li>
            <li><a href="#select">Select</a></li>
            <li><a href="#input">Input</a></li>
            <li><a href="#checkradio">Checkboxes &amp; Radios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#switches">Switches</a></li>
        </ul>
```

So when I'm on mobile the above gets turned into a simple menu with the 3 bars when then folds down the links.

Similar to how the Bootstrap navigation menu works, but so it doesn't conflict with this.

I ideally want to use the built in stuff with Bootstrap for this, good example of what i am after:

http://ux.mailchimp.com/patterns/forms

If you shrink the browser you will see that list turn into a menu on mobile.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use Bootstrap? Also, what did you try so far? Just in case, there are thousands of ways to do it, most of them require JS or jQuery, do a Google search and choose any of them

Comment: Yeah i ideally want to use Bootstrap for this - the built in stuff if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Some simple modifications to your HTML, [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and Javascript should allow you to replicate this behaviour.

I would suggest that you begin by creating the media-query to alter the applied styles based on device width.

**CSS - Mobile first**

```
.list-inline {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.list-inline-active {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}

.list-inline li {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .list-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .list-inline {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }    

  .list-inline li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

**HTML - Add toggle button/icon**

```
<button class="list-toggle">Show list</button>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$('.list-toggle').click(function(){
  $('.list-inline').toggleClass('list-inline-active');
});
```

This method simply uses a button to toggle a class on the unordered-list element. The toggled class contains styles to make the list visible on mobile.

I've created a simple [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7o30r924/) to show this in action.

It's worth noting that this behaviour is almost entirely replicable without the use of Javascript at all. It would involve the use of checkboxes and the ':checked' pseudo selector. However Bootstrap 3 does use Javascript.

I hope this helps.